# Why Your Lawn Mower Won’t Start After Winter?

Tags: starting, small-engine, lawnmower

What are the most common reasons for a lawn mower not starting after being stored during the winter, and what steps can I take to troubleshoot and fix the issue?
I have found the solution for this article [here.](https://www.homegreeneryguides.com/lawn-mower-wont-start-after-winter/)

Answer (score 3):

The most common cause is probably that the carburetor is clogged up with gunk. This doesn't allow fuel to flow into the engine and it won't run. The reason the gunk gets there is caused most readily by fuels containing ethanol. The ethanol absorbs water. The mixture of the two then clogs up the passages and things aren't pretty.

What is the easiest way to prevent this? If you have a shutoff valve between your fuel tank and the carb, turn it to the off position. Then, start up your mower and let it run until it dies. This will ensure the vast majority of the fuel has been cleaned out of the carburetor and then there's no gumming to be had. If you don't have a cutoff valve, then drain all the fuel you can out of the tank and then let it run until it dies. Same result.

To protect all of my small engines I do two things. First I use a fuel stabilizer such as STA-BIL. This will help the fuel not to absorb water (especially the fuel which is sitting in the gas cans waiting to be used). Then secondly I will run them dry when I'm through using them for the year. When it's time to fire them up again, I either dump new fuel in (if I've had to drain it all) or turn the cut off valve to the on position. My engines fire up fine every time without fail.

Comment: thankyou so much your opinion sir